# Sending mp3 file from YouTube to telegram without downloading a file

Tags: pytube

I have a code with an mp3 file download from YouTube, what method should I use to send an mp3 file to Telegram without downloading file?

I want to transfer mp3 bytes so as not to download the file and immediately send them to telegram

Comment: It's unclear do you accept to download the MP3 file and then upload it to telegram **or** you directly want to transmit the MP3 bytes to telegram ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to directly transfer bytes mp3